# Facing issue 401 unauthorized when getting the servicenow access token

Tags: java, eclipse, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, servicenow-hrsd

i am getting an unauthorized issue while getting the access token from servicenow in eclipse java but  it works fine in postman and the java code is works fine for the another servicenow credentials how to fix it can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

There is lack of sufficient details to exactly find the root cause of issue you are mentioning.

But for a easier solution, in postman , you can get the equivalent code by clicking on the code tab on upper right below the save button. You can compare the Java equivalent or any language that is comfortable for you and your code and check whether there is any difference , notably the headers

Comment: i am using the postman code in my java application it is fine for the one credentials and not works for the another credentials